# how to map an dto included foreign key id to object one to many relationship

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an entity like this and when i want to create a new product i want to post also category of id that involves this product.
is any way ta access category by id ...i try to create a constructor to category with id as param but this does not solve my problem

```java
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name="products")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name="base64Image")
    private String base64Image;
    @Column(name="price")
    private Double price;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade =CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private Category category;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="discount_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Discount discount;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
    private Set<ProductLocation> productLocations;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name="created_at")
    private LocalDateTime created_at;
    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name="updated_at")
    private LocalDateTime updated_at;

}
```

I have this dto but when using mapstruct category id of product created remains null`

```java
@Data
public class ProductRequestDto {
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String base64Image;
    private Double price;

    private Long categoryId;

    @JsonIgnore
    private Discount discount=null;

}
```

the mapper interface that i have used

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface ProductMapper {
    ProductMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(ProductMapper.class);

    List<ProductResponseDto> productToDto(List<Product> products);


    Product dtoToProduct(ProductRequestDto product);
    ProductResponseDto productToDto(Product product);

    void update(@MappingTarget Product product, ProductRequestDto productDto);
}
```

can you suggest any solution

Answer (score 0):

For me best option is to

change mapper to be `abstract class` instead `interface` adding annotation to it
`@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")`

adding `@Mapping(target = "Category", source = "categoryId")` to `productToDto` method

Autowiring `categoryRepository` to Mapper

and creating custom method for mapping from id to Entity

```
public Category resolveCategory(Long categoryId) {
    if (categoryId == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return categoryRepository.getById(categoryId);
}
```